# Why is mkdir failing to make directories?

Tags: linux

I've got a script which calls "mkdir" like this:

```
mkdir -p dir0/dir1 dir0/dir1/dir2.0 dir0/dir1/dir2.1 dir0/dir1/dir2.2
```

It is run on a very heavily loaded NFS server over NFS3 and about half the time the script runs it works fine - all the directories list above are created. The other half of the time only dir0/dir1 is created but none of the dir2.* directories. Strangely, mkdir seems to exit 0 even though not all the directories are created.

Any idea why this is happening? At least an error code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

try checking verbose, if that can help.

mkdir -p -v dir0/dir1 dir0/dir1/dir2.0 dir0/dir1/dir2.1 dir0/dir1/dir2.2

Comment: I've added it - will be curious to see if anything pops up. I don't know if it's the answer but good suggestion!